# MPMediaPickerController doesn't show podcasts or audiobooks in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, mpmediapickercontroller

We have an app that works fine on iOS 5 and iOS 6, which allows user to pick some media to play with `MPMediaPickerController`. In these versions, the user could also pick audiobooks and podcasts in addition to songs.

In iOS 7, however, there are only Songs, Playlists, Artists and Albums to choose from, but we'd like to be able to pick podcasts and audiobooks. Is this a feature or a configuration issue?

I'm creating the controller as `[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAny]` - so it should present me with other media types than music according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this, when I use  `[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio]` instead of `MPMediaTypeAny`, audiobooks and podcasts appear.